# Phonegap iOS app not allowing inputs on forms in an iframe

Tags: javascript, cordova, iframe, phonegap-build

iOS 9.3.2
Phonegap Build 6.1

We're loading an iFrame from another vendor into our iOS app. The form loads perfectly fine. We tap on the form field and it does not allow any inputs. This occurs on multiple iPhones. The same app works on mobile safari and chrome. Phonegap is when these issues begin.

We've made changes to the CSS for

`-webkit-user-select: none;`

now everything is

`input { -webkit-user-select: text; }`

We've disabled faskclick.js and made the changes suggested, still the same thing.

Not sure what could be causing the problem. Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: With all JS/CSS disabled, the issue still occurs. However, when I hold delete and keep deleting an empty field, I am able to then type this in a field

However, when I hold down the delete key and delete any contents in a form field for a few seconds, when I stop I am able to then type this in that form field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Shazron and risingj at Adobe, this is likely an Apple rendering issue in UIWebView. They have no control regarding UIWebView's bugs, so this is something everyone should take into consideration. We've downgrade to cordova 3.7.0 and use "cordova-plugin-wkwebview", it works as intended.

Comment: For those using Cordova or beginning to use Reactnative, Consider using WKWebView